# How to import big data to NDB

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have a NDB model:

```
class mymodel(ndb.Model):
  id =ndb.IntegerProperty(indexed=True)
  region_id = ndb.IntegerProperty()
  name = ndb.TextProperty()
  address =ndb.TextProperty()
  is_enabled   = ndb.BooleanProperty()
```

My app is High Replication type, I want to import over 3,000,000 records from my data in local. I try import by csv file,every time i can import 3,000-4,000 records.
Please show me the right way for this data.

Answer (score 1):

The [remote api](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/remoteapi) seems a perfect candidate for this.